# Armature Arm and Leg FK's are not moving the character

Tags: rigging

[image]

I have a human character which I have rigged with Rigify. I am able to move the FK pieces in places such as the face, but not in the arms or the legs.

My best guess is that the automatic weights have failed in some way.

Why do my arm and leg FK's not move the character?

`.blend`: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LGxfy5K8vaCcb0WP1eJ515MW10RWUuIh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: or maybe the bones that are supposed to deform the mesh have their Deform option disabled? Please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots file has been shared

Comment: oh ok I see, but I don't know Rigify enough, I hope someone will help

Comment: Your file is not downloadable (gets a file corrupted error) but: is the IK chain working? Try to move the hand bone or even the Hip bone: is the rig behaving correctly? Maybe it's just the IK/FK switch set to IK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rigify, you have to switch to FK to use it. Set this switch in properties panel (press <kbd>N</kbd> to view panel, bone has to be selected) to 1 for the both hands and also for legs:

[image]