# Rig not moving my model/mesh

Tags: rigging

I am new to blender but I know to parent the rig, and none of the armature deform options are working.[image]

Blend/Blend1 File

https://pasteall.org/blend/51a4e2b9ca1c447da2b100b7ffaf5318
https://pasteall.org/blend/c244b8421782437e93f703817cad41d1

When I try to use my rig's controls none of them do anything other than move the rig controls themselves, I've tried the basic solutions I've found online as well as similar and suggested solutions I have found on this site but none of them seem to fix this.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Blender.SE! Could you please clarify exactly what your problem is and give a few more details so we can help?

Comment: Yes, when I try to use my rig's controls none of them do anything other than move the rig controls themselves, I've tried the basic solutions I've found online but none of them seem to fix this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Armature Arm and Leg FK's are not moving the character](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/262572/armature-arm-and-leg-fks-are-not-moving-the-character)

Comment: The fix mentioned in the post only causes the rig controls to also move the connected rig controls, in my image you can see the hand controls don't move along with arm controls, now they do, but the arm mesh/model still doesn't move.

Comment: The mesh is bound to the *metarig* (check the armature modifier on it.) To fix it clear the body's parent (Alt+P) and bind it to the *rig* armature (Ctrl+P, with automatic weights). *rig* must be the active object, selected last.

Comment: That's fixed it, thank you.